# Disallowing /lev1/*.html, but allowing /lev1/lev2/*.html

Tags: robots.txt

Must be disallowed:

```
/lev1/*.html
```

Must be allowed:

```
/lev1/lev2/*.html
```

Is it posible with robots.txt?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

https://geoffkenyon.com/how-to-use-wildcards-robots-txt/

To exclude all robots from part of the server

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /lev1/lev2/*.html
```